# Facebook swift iOS get user mobile number

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

is there anyway I can get the user mobile phone number from Facebook latest SDK or Graph API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the phone number. There is no permission, and there is no data field for this in the API.